# Change Process priority does not work

Tags: c#, windows

I run an Audio Repeater application which allows me to play sound through my headset & Speakers at the same time.
The Application itself has an ability to set itself to "RealTime" but it only sets it to high so at the moment I have to set it myself in Task Manager.

I decided to automate this so I wrote a little script in C# that would change the process priority for me (That I would add to start up once I've finished)

```
namespace ProcessRealtime
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("audiorepeater");
            foreach (Process proc in processes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Changing Priority for: "+proc.Id+" To RealTime");
                proc.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime;
                if (proc.PriorityClass == ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Worked");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it does not apply the changes.
[image: Screenshot of Desktop]

Does anyone know why this will not work?

Comment: Umm, you might trying running your program as an Admin. This may be necessary in some cases.

Comment: Can confirm that what @JABFreeware said is correct.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead Thanks, I added an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to run YOUR script with administrative privilege.

Comment: I tested this on Win7 by running Visual Studio as Administrator and normally. As Administrator worked (whereas non Administrator just set it to High, as per the OP's issue).

Comment: Thanks, was a bit of an oversight by me since Task Manager doesn't appear to require Admin to raise to Realtime but cool. Just need to find a way to make it work without User interaction (Allowing to run as administrator).
I was thinking of making it a service.

Comment: @OliverBaker if you are an administrative user Task Manager can do a "transparent elevation" to elevate itself without a UAC prompt. [Only software signed by the "Microsoft Windows" certificate can do this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.uac.aspx).

Answer (score 11):

Try this :

```
using (Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
    p.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can run as an administrator or remove UAC because you need rights to access to a Process you did not run.

This works for me :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// #define DEBUG

namespace ProcessRealtime
{
    class PUBG_RealTime
    {
        static string processName = "TslGame";
        static ProcessPriorityClass newPriority = ProcessPriorityClass.High;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#if DEBUG
            PutDebug("Start!");
#endif
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
#if DEBUG
            PutDebug(processes.Length + " processed found");
#endif
            foreach (Process proc in processes)
            {
#if DEBUG
                PutDebug("New process found");
#endif
                Console.WriteLine("Changing Priority for id:" + proc.Id + " to " + newPriority.ToString());
                proc.PriorityClass = newPriority;
#if DEBUG
                PutDebug("Changed priority for " + proc.Id);
#endif
            }
#if DEBUG
            PutDebug("No more processes..");
#endif
            Console.Write("Press a key, it's over !");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

#if DEBUG
        static bool debug = true;
        static int debugInc = 1;
        static void PutDebug(string info = "")
        {
            if(debug){
                Console.WriteLine("Debug" + debugInc + ": " + info);
                debugInc++;
            }
        }
#endif
    }
}
```