# Task.Delay delays too long

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I've created a multi task program. This program has around 20 main tasks and each of them calls some sub tasks to operate file I/Os. I wanted each main task to repeat periodically every 500ms, so I enterd the code Task.Delay(500).

The problem is Task.Delay delays a lot more than 500ms sometimes. There is a case it delays more than 3 seconds.
How can I fix it?

The original progam is so big that I created a sample program below.
(1) If Task.Delay is on, over-delay happens.
(2) If Thead.Sleep is on, over-delay doesn't happen.

ThreadPool.SetMinThreads() doesn't seem to resolve it.

Thanks.

```
class Program
{

    const int DELAY_TIME = 500;
    const int TASKS = 100;
    const int WAITS = 100;
    const int WARNING_THRESHOLD = 100;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(workerThreads: 200, completionPortThreads: 200);

        Console.WriteLine("*** Start...");
        Test();
        Console.WriteLine("*** Done!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Test()
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int taskId = 0; taskId < TASKS; taskId++)
        {
            tasks.Add(DelaysAsync(taskId));
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }

    static async Task DelaysAsync(int taskId)
    {
        await Task.Yield();

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        for (int i = 0; i < WAITS; i++)
        {
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            await Task.Delay(DELAY_TIME).ConfigureAwait(false);   // (1)
            //Thread.Sleep(DELAY_TIME);   // (2)
            sw.Stop();

            Console.Write($"Task({taskId})_iter({i}) Elapsed={sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
            if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > DELAY_TIME + WARNING_THRESHOLD)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" *********** Too late!! ************");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like limited number of threads available maybe.  What values do you have from `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads` ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads` and get `workerThreads=2047, completionPortThreads=1000`.

Comment: I have less available threads, older machine.  It may be the debugger, I've run without debugging and haven't run into what you're experiencing

Comment: I run it on Release and Debug to end up the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I could find the answer. I changed the previous sample program like below. The main difference is using StopWatch or DateTime to measure time durations.
In StopWatch version, many delays happen.
In DateTime version, no or at least very little delays happen(s).

I guess that the cause is the contention of Timer that is used by both StopWatch and Task.Delay. I concluded that I should not use StopWatch and Task.Delay together.

Thank you.

```
class Program
{

    const int DELAY_TIME = 500;
    const int TASKS = 100;
    const int WAITS = 100;
    const int WARNING_THRESHOLD = 500;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        {
            p.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime;

            //ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(workerThreads: 200, completionPortThreads: 200);
            int workerThreads;
            int completionPortThreads;
            ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out workerThreads, out completionPortThreads);
            Console.WriteLine($"{workerThreads}, {completionPortThreads}");

            Console.WriteLine("*** Start...");
            Test();
            Console.WriteLine("*** Done!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    private static void Test()
    {
        int totalCount = 0;
        List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
        for (int taskId = 0; taskId < TASKS; taskId++)
        {
            //tasks.Add(DelaysWithStopWatchAsync(taskId)); // many delays
            tasks.Add(DelaysWithDateTimeAsync(taskId));  // no delays
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            totalCount += task.Result;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Total counts of deday = {totalCount}");
    }

    static async Task<int> DelaysWithStopWatchAsync(int taskId)
    {
        await Task.Yield();

        int count = 0;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        for (int i = 0; i < WAITS; i++)
        {
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            await Task.Delay(DELAY_TIME).ConfigureAwait(false);   // (1)
            //Thread.Sleep(DELAY_TIME);   // (2)
            sw.Stop();

            Console.Write($"task({taskId})_iter({i}) elapsed={sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
            if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > DELAY_TIME + WARNING_THRESHOLD)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($" *********** Too late!! ************");
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        return count;

    }

    static async Task<int> DelaysWithDateTimeAsync(int taskId)
    {
        await Task.Yield();

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < WAITS; i++)
        {
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            await Task.Delay(DELAY_TIME).ConfigureAwait(false);   // (1)
            //Thread.Sleep(DELAY_TIME);   // (2)
            DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
            int duration = (end - start).Milliseconds;

            Console.Write($"Task({taskId})_iter({i}) Elapsed={duration}");
            if (duration > DELAY_TIME + WARNING_THRESHOLD)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($" *********** Too late!! ************");
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        return count;

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running your program on linux using .NET core?  I'm seeing something similar to your original issue.  I suspect the stopwatch doesn't behave well on linux, especially when the code in question is capable of being scheduled on more than one thread.

Comment: No. I'm running it on Windows10. I suspect there is some common locking object between StopWatch and Task.Delay.

Comment: You might try calling ThreadPool.SetMinThreads() with a larger worker thread count (like 50).  This appeared to fix the issues I was having.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve run your test, with .NET 4.6.1 and VS 2017. Here on Xeon E3-1230 v3 CPU it never printed “Too late”, the Elapsed value was within 498-527 ms.

The Thread.Sleep version performed very similarly, 500-528ms per sleep, however the total execution time was much longer because the runtime refused to create 100 OS threads, that’s way too many, so less than 100 DelaysAsync functions ran in parallel. The debugger showed me there were 27 worker threads in Thread.Sleep version and only 9 worker threads in Task.Delay version.

I think you have other apps on your PC creating too many threads and consuming too much CPU. Windows tries to load balance threads evenly so when the whole system is CPU bound, more native threads = more CPU time and therefore less jitter.

If that’s your case and you want to prioritize your app in the scheduler, instead of using Thread.Sleep and more threads, [raise the priority](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15112778/126995) of your process.

Comment: I raised the priority as High or RealTime, but in vain. But I've gotten a hint from you. My CPU is i7-6500U, so I tried it on other PC of CPU Xeon E5-2630 v4 and then no "Too late" showed up. So, I suspect it strongly depends on number of CPUs or threads. I have no time for further investigation for now so I'll investigate more on next week and report the result here.

Comment: @nak326 Your laptop CPU is still good. It definitely should not be 3 seconds delays in that code. I’ve just tested on my laptop, it has i3-6157U, delays were within 499-543ms.
I think there’s something strange with your particular laptop. Could be related to power saving, ACPI drivers, problematic software or drivers you’re running. Ensure you’ve got no errors/warnings messages in system or application event logs, ensure CPU is not 100% loaded, if you’re running non-Microsoft antivirus try disabling that…

Comment: @nak326 You can also try upgrading .NET framework. I’ve built the test for 4.6.1 because that was the default for VS2017, but actually I have 4.6.2 installed on both PCs.

Comment: I don't see any strange with my laptop. and I already use .NET Framework 4.6.1 and tried some other versions too.